# How do I Simulate Users using Jython Script?

Tags: java, python, jython, grinder

I need to create a user journey such as :

User is on the home page --> randomly clicks on particular item --> views the item stays for  about 10 seconds --> then again goes back  and clicks on another random item.

how do i generate a test script using jython? I am using Grinder tool

Comment: I read the title as 'stimulate'.

Answer (score 0):

Shashank,

I think your question is too broad to get a detailed response.  If you ask a more specific question I think you will get a better answer.

I would say there are two general approaches available for doing what you want, and you could have success with either option:

- Write your test directly in Jython.  The script documentation (http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/scripts.html) and script gallery (http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/script-gallery.html) will be helpful to you in this.
- Using the HTTP proxy, perform the actions in a web browser that you wish your test to perform.  (http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/tcpproxy.html)  The proxy will capture your browser actions and convert them into a Jython script.  After this happens, a small amount of additional work will be required on your part to modify the generated script to detect the list of items available and randomly select one.

My own personal preference is to code up the Grinder scripts from scratch.  YMMV.